# How to merge two cells in the mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm registering on the site and have already learned how to add cells and remove them using nodejs.Now I need a clue!I need that when a user connects an account such as facebook to an account, his token is tied to the main account. To do this, you need to connect, as in the SQL query of the database, to have a link to the other, so that the user can not bind the account again to another database. How can I arrange this?

Comment: Can you please explain better what kind of operation you want to perform?

Comment: Your terminology is unclear but I believe what you are asking about is a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/). If the Facebook token is optional, you would also want to [make your unique index sparse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-with-unique-constraint) so that the unique constraint is only applied when a value is present:  `db.members.createIndex({ "facebook_token": 1 }, { unique: true, sparse:true })` .